# NSNumberFormatter gives wrong currency

Tags: currency, nsnumberformatter

I have UILabel in which i want to show $ also it works fine but problem is that it works on simulator correct but when i test this code on device instead $ it shows Rs (Rupess) any idea how to fix this issue.

```
  NSNumber *number=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:1000];


   NSString *No = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:number numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
   NSLog(@"%@", No);

   UILabel * text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",No];

   NSLog(@"%@",text);
```

Comment: The issue is with your phone settings ...

Answer (score 1):

Because by default the formatter will use the locale specified on the device it is being run on. If you want to force a particular display you need to use `setLocale:` and supply the appropriate `NSLocale` instance.

Comment: how to use setLocal and NSLocal please help me out

Comment: There is a whole set of documentation. You will not get ready made code for that in this community.

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue.

1. As you are using `localizedStringFromNumber` and `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` to format number it's giving you the number format as per your region.
2. If you go to your simulator Setting - General - International - Region Format. It must be United State. Hence it shows $ when you run it on simulator.
3. If you check the same thing in your device. It'll show Region Format as India. Hence, it's showing Rs. sign.
4. If you want to see the $ sign just go ahead and change the setting in Device.

Comment: without changing from device can't we change the code instead of localizedString use any other

Comment: The code which you have set is perfect. That's the perfect way of formatting the amount.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you want to set the result of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",No]` to a `UILabel` instance.

The other answers seem the most likely, choosing the correct device regional settings and using your existing code to output the value in the local format.

However if anyone is interested in outputting a number with an arbitrary currency format:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencyCode:@"INR"];

NSString *text = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];

NSLog(@"%@", text);

// Release formatter as required
```

Though why you'd do this instead of just using the currency symbol and a basic string I'm not sure :p

```
NSString *text = @"₹1,000.00";
```

Answer (score 0):

you got this issue because in device setting->general->international->reion format -> is INDIA

just change it to the country of your choice like if you want $ symbol then select USA